# rubyでオブジェクトを綺麗にまとめたい

Tags: ruby

```
[
  {
    :id => 1,
    :data => 1
  },
  {
    :id => 1,
    :data => 2
  },
  {
    :id => 2,
    :data => 1
  },
  {
    :id => 2,
    :data => 2
  }
]
```

↓こうしたい

```
[
  {
    :id => 1,
    :data => [1,2]
  },
  {
    :id => 2,
    :data => [1,2]
  },
]
```

ループがたくさんになってしまう上に、うまくいきません。

Answer (score 1):

こんな感じでどうでしょうか？

```
objects = [
  {
    :id => 1,
    :data => 1
  },
  {
    :id => 1,
    :data => 2
  },
  {
    :id => 2,
    :data => 1
  },
  {
    :id => 2,
    :data => 2
  }
]
objects
  .map {|h| [h[:id], h[:data]] }
  .group_by(&:first)
  .map {|id, arr| { id: id, data: arr.map(&:last) } }
# => [{:id=>1, :data=>[1, 2]}, {:id=>2, :data=>[1, 2]}]
```

多少読みづらくても構わないなら、こんな書き方もできます。
ループの回数は少なくなりそうです。

```
data_holder = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = { id: k, data: [] } }
objects.each_with_object(data_holder) { |object, holder|
  holder[object[:id]][:data] << object[:data]
}.values
```

`each_with_object` の代わりに `tap` を使うパターンもあります。

```
Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = { id: k, data: [] } }.tap {|hash|
  objects.each do |obj|
    id, data = obj.values_at(:id, :data)
    hash[id][:data] << data
  end
}.values
```

お好きな方法で実装してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

```
objects = [
  {
    :id => 1,
    :data => 1
  },
  {
    :id => 1,
    :data => 2
  },
  {
    :id => 2,
    :data => 1
  },
  {
    :id => 2,
    :data => 2
  }
]
objects    
  .group_by{|h| h[:id]}
  .map {|k, h| {id: k, data: h.map {|h| h[:data]} }}
```

Junichi Itoさんのコードを参考に
group_byの前にarrayにしない方法も追記致します。

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = {}
array.each do |obj|
  if hash[obj[:id]]
    hash[obj[:id]] << obj[:data]
  else
    hash[obj[:id]] = [obj[:data]]
  end
end
pp hash.to_a.map{|a| {id: a.first, data: a.last}}
```

Answer (score 0):

私も挑戦してみました。

```
input = [
  {
    :id => 1,
    :data => 1
  },
  {
    :id => 1,
    :data => 2
  },
  {
    :id => 2,
    :data => 1
  },
  {
    :id => 2,
    :data => 2
  }
]

output = input.reduce({}) { |hash, item|
  ( hash[item[:id]] ||= [] ) << item[:data]
  hash
}.map { |key, value| { id: key, data: value } }

pp output
# => [{:id=>1, :data=>[1, 2]}, {:id=>2, :data=>[1, 2]}]
```